# Difference bet will or would in conditional sentences

Tags: difference

I read this sentence in a book."if I tell her about this ,how would that do?"
I don't understand why would is used with if +present tense.could you please explain this?

Comment: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+do+what+would%2Cif+I+do+what+will%2Cif+I+did+what+would%2Cif+I+did+what+will&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10), showing that *if I **do** what **will...*** and *if I **did** what **would...*** are common, but the "mixed tense" versions *if I **do** what **would...*** and *if I **did** what **will...*** don't occur often enough to show on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the sentence should be one of these two constructions

> If I tell her about this, how **will** that do?
>
> If I **told** her about this, how would that do?

Then the grammar is consistent, the second one being in the subjunctive mood.